# Java stream groupingBy key as max salary employee and value as all employee of department

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of `Employee`

```
public class Employee {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
  private Double salary;
  private Department department;
}

List<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(
      new Employee("Tom Jones", 45, 12000.00,Department.MARKETING),
      new Employee("Harry Major", 26, 20000.00, Department.LEGAL),
      new Employee("Ethan Hardy", 65, 30000.00, Department.LEGAL),
      new Employee("Nancy Smith", 22, 15000.00, Department.MARKETING),
      new Employee("Catherine Jones", 21, 18000.00, Department.HR),
      new Employee("James Elliot", 58, 24000.00, Department.OPERATIONS),
      new Employee("Frank Anthony", 55, 32000.00, Department.MARKETING),
      new Employee("Michael Reeves", 40, 45000.00, Department.OPERATIONS));
```

I want to get `Map<Employee, List<Employee>>` where map key is for each Department's max salary employee and value is all employee of that department.
I am trying to groupingBy but it gives all employee with Department map. How to get all max salary employee as map key ?

```
Map<Department,List<Employee>> employeeMap
        = employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment));
```

Comment: Side note: Use primitives when possible. Doing `int age` and `double salary` would probably be better, since it's 2 less objects per employee

Comment: Another side note: Don't use `double` for salary, use `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the required result as follows:

```
Map<Employee, List<Employee>> result = employees.stream()
         .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary).reversed())
         .collect(groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, LinkedHashMap::new, toList())).values().stream()
         .collect(toMap(l -> l.get(0), Function.identity()));
```

There's probably better and more efficient solutions out there and I would have exhausted those ideas had i not been on my phone.

Comment: Why `sorted` needed here, can you explain a bit.

Comment: @KmarlonPereira we sort once before the reduction operations so we can later get the employee with the highest salary for each group. without sorting beforehand we would need to stream over each group at some point in the pipeline to get the employee with the highest salary as the key. something like WJS's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work.

- It first determines the employees by department then
- Then it groups them based on the largest salary of the departments employee

```
Map<Employee, List<Employee>> map = employeeList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                e->e.getValue().stream()
                        .max(Comparator.comparing(
                                Employee::getSalary))
                        .get(),
                Entry::getValue));
```

Overriding `toString` in `Employee` class to return name, salary, and department,
here is the output.

```
map.forEach((k,v)->{System.out.println(k);
    for (Employee e: v) {
          System.out.printf("    %s%n", e);
    }
    System.out.println();
});
```

Prints

```
Frank Anthony, 32000.0, MARKETING}
    {Tom Jones, 12000.0, MARKETING}
    {Nancy Smith, 15000.0, MARKETING}
    {Frank Anthony, 32000.0, MARKETING}

{Michael Reeves, 45000.0, OPERATIONS}
    {James Elliot, 24000.0, OPERATIONS}
    {Michael Reeves, 45000.0, OPERATIONS}

{Catherine Jones, 18000.0, HR}
    {Catherine Jones, 18000.0, HR}

{Ethan Hardy, 30000.0, LEGAL}
    {Harry Major, 20000.0, LEGAL}
    {Ethan Hardy, 30000.0, LEGAL}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion - you can stream the values instead of using `getValue`

Comment: @user I appreciate that.  But I am streaming the entrySet so I don't think I can do it. (or couldn't get it to work) Besides, if I did that I would be sort of copying your answer which wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: Actually this is better. Because they’re entries, they don’t turn into 2d collections like in my answer. +1

Comment: Don't you think operation in map key is very expensive  ?

Comment: Not really. It seems to do comparatively fine. Unfortunately, I don't have jmh setup to check it out more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Map<Employee, List<Employee>> employeeMap = employeeList.stream()
      .collect(groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment))
      .values().stream()
      .collect(
        groupingBy(
            (es) -> es.stream()
              .max(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getSalary())).get()
        )
      ).entrySet().stream()
      .collect(toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> e.getValue().iterator().next()
      ));
```

Output:

```
{(Michael Reeves, 40, 45000.0, OPERATIONS)=[(James Elliot, 58, 24000.0, OPERATIONS), (Michael Reeves, 40, 45000.0, OPERATIONS)], 
(Catherine Jones, 21, 18000.0, HR)=[(Catherine Jones, 21, 18000.0, HR)], 
(Ethan Hardy, 65, 30000.0, LEGAL)=[(Harry Major, 26, 20000.0, LEGAL), (Ethan Hardy, 65, 30000.0, LEGAL)], 
(Frank Anthony, 55, 32000.0, MARKETING)=[(Tom Jones, 45, 12000.0, MARKETING), (Nancy Smith, 22, 15000.0, MARKETING), (Frank Anthony, 55, 32000.0, MARKETING)]}
```

Link to repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/CluelessAwesomeLevel#Main.java

Comment: I'd rather use `.max(Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary)).get()` than `.max((e1, e2) -> e1.salary > e2.salary ? 1 : (e1.salary < e2.salary ? -1 : 0)).get()` for readability and conciseness.

Comment: on another note, your code doesn't seem to be correct in terms of what it produces as an end result but i'll let the OP be the judge to that.

Comment: there's several issues with the result to mention a couple where is `Nancy Smith` in your result?. the marketing mapping should be `{Frank Anthony, 32000.0, MARKETING}=
   [ {Tom Jones, 12000.0, MARKETING},
    {Nancy Smith, 15000.0, MARKETING},
    {Frank Anthony, 32000.0, MARKETING}]` not `{Frank Anthony, 55, 32000.0, MARKETING}=[{Tom Jones, 45, 12000.0, MARKETING}]` , the key should also be in the corresponding list. etc... do you get where i am going with this? .

Comment: @OusmaneD. I see. Wow, I really missed that. In earlier revisions, that part was fixed but there was a weird singleton list. Thanks again